# Convert Python Dataframe in 1 Line Dataframe where columns and index values are concatinated

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the following structure, but much larger

```
    1y   2y   3y
1w  2    8    40
2w  3    10   50 
1m  4    12   60
```

What is a good fast way in python to convert it to a single line dataframe:

```
         1w/1y  1w/2y  1w/3y  2w/1y  2w/2y  2w/3y  1m/1y  1m/2y  1m/3y
NewIndex  2       8     40     3       10    50     4       12    60
```

The new index will eventually be dates, because I have the following data stored in a separate CSVs for every date and I want to convert it to a single dataframe to run some stats on it.

Many thanks
[Here's the image as the text got misaligned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3s7V.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3s7V.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [16]: x = df.stack()

In [17]: x
Out[17]:
1w  1y     2
    2y     8
    3y    40
2w  1y     3
    2y    10
    3y    50
1m  1y     4
    2y    12
    3y    60
dtype: int64

In [18]: new = pd.DataFrame(x.values, index=x.index.map('/'.join)).T

In [19]: new
Out[19]:
   1w/1y  1w/2y  1w/3y  2w/1y  2w/2y  2w/3y  1m/1y  1m/2y  1m/3y
0      2      8     40      3     10     50      4     12     60
```

or better without transposing:

```
In [30]: new = pd.DataFrame(x.values[None, :], columns=x.index.map('/'.join), index=[0])

In [31]: new
Out[31]:
   1w/1y  1w/2y  1w/3y  2w/1y  2w/2y  2w/3y  1m/1y  1m/2y  1m/3y
0      2      8     40      3     10     50      4     12     60
```